# .htaccess on VPS results in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a big problem with this `.htaccess`, I moved from webhosting to my VPS but the problem is that on webhosting it works while on my dedicated server with Apache2 it does not work. The error is:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files ~ "\.log$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
    php_value register_globals off
    php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://URLWEBSITE/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^URLWEBSITE
RewriteRule (.*) https://URLWEBSITE/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^anime/(.*)$ ./anime_read.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^liveaction/(.*)$ ./liveaction_read.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ ./news_read.php?id=$1


</ifModule>
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Include the results of the network traffic to show the redirect loop. In exemplifying the domain you seem to have introduced (more) errors? How is SSL handled on the VPS?

Answer (score 1):

What is the intent of the rules here?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^URLWEBSITE
RewriteRule (.*) https://URLWEBSITE/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will cause all requests with a HOST header of your website to be redirected to your website... resulting in `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

I'm not sure what you intended those rules to do, but they're an obvious loop.

Comment: Removed, but is not working.

Comment: My guess is that this code is supposed to handle the canonical www redirect, but it's been "corrupted" when trying to exemplify the domain. (Otherwise, it wouldn't have worked on the "webhosting" either.)